# Logging node on the client by parsing util.inspect

Tags: node.js, json, logging

I'm trying to log node.js objects on the client. JSON.stringify gives me:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

`util.inspect` doesn't seem to produce a string that I can turn back into an object after it's been sent to the client through websockets.

Is there a way to inspect the object on the client side then?

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon this issue many times in the past when trying to `JSON.stringify()` a Circular structure. Thus, the [circular-structure-stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-structure-stringify) npm package had been made to circumvent it. Simply put, its usage is similar to `JSON.stringify(circular-obj)` and can be used like such:

```
import CircularStructureStringify from 'circular-structure-stringify';

console.log(CircularStructureStringify(THE_CIRCULAR_JSON));
```

Comment: Just tried but it does not go deep enough into the object. So its not really working for my case.